# Continue to receive new events for completed REQUEST_STREAM in rsocket

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, rsocket

Given an Rsocket endpoint (Spring)

```java
    @MessageMapping("chat.{chatId}")
    Flux<Message> getChats(@DestinationVariable String chatId) {
        Mono<Chat> data = chatRepository.findById(chatId);
        return data.map(chatGroup -> chatGroup.getMessages())
                .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
    }


   public interface ChatRepository extends FirestoreReactiveRepository<Chat> {

   }
```

and a client connecting to it via websocket: JS (Rsocket 1.x)

```js
const makeConnector = () => {
      return new RSocketConnector({
        setup: {
          dataMimeType: 'application/json',
          keepAlive: 100000,
          lifetime: 100000,
          metadataMimeType: 'message/x.rsocket.routing.v0',
        },
        transport: new WebsocketClientTransport({
          url: 'ws://localhost:7000/rsocket',
        }),
      });
};

client()
  .connect()
  .then((socket) => {
    const requester = socket.requestStream(
      {
        data: undefined,
        metadata: Buffer.concat([
          Buffer.from(String.fromCharCode('chat.chatId'.length)),
          Buffer.from('chat.chatId'),
        ]),
      },
      10,
      {
        onError: (e) => console.log('error getting data', e),
        onNext: (payload, isComplete) => {
          const parsedData: Chat = JSON.parse(payload.data.toString());
          requester.request(5); // request the next 5 chats
        },
        onComplete: () => {
          console.log('complete');
        },
        onExtension: () => {
          console.log('on extension');
        },
      }
    );
  });
```

When the `requestStream` data is completed. (ie. `complete` is printed in console)

Then the new events are no longer received after complete. Is it possible to listen to new events if a stream is completed?

I went around this using an intervals, but this introduce new issues such as duplicate chats being received. I can filter it on the frontend side, but there must be a better way to do this

```java
return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).flatMap(x -> {
   return chatService.findChats(matchId);
});
```

Comment: Your current backend code takes a snapshot of received messages at a given time, and send it back. If you require a livestream of messages, then you should change your strategy, and not get messages back from the database. You need a "change feed" or a message queue or a  hot flux somewhere, from which you can poll messages to send them back. But without more details about your backend app (how messages are received and treated), it is difficult to provide a right answer.

Comment: @amanin thank you. I used `FirestoreReactiveRepository` (https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#reactive-repositories) to query the database

It is not possible to listen to active events with this approach. To listen to updates a listener needs to be registered via native `onSnapshot` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#java) or adding a listener into the `Firestore` provided spring bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSocket-JS does not provide by default any "re-subscription" mechanism when a connection is closed : Meaning when your connection is closed or completed, you can not receive events on this connection anymore.

In RSocket, when the WebSocket connection status is 'CLOSED' or 'ERROR', the subscription is cancelled. Meaning you can't receive any new events anymore.

You can see it in their RSocketClient.js, line 91 : https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/blob/master/packages/rsocket-core/src/RSocketClient.js

If you would like to continue receiving new events after your current connection was closed, you need to create another one.
To do it, you can inspire you from the example provided by RSocket here : https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/blob/master/packages/rsocket-examples/src/ReconnectExample.js

Personally, I used it in the current project I'm working on, but I re-worked it a bit, in order to add a few additional things :

- A maximum number of retry, in order to still kill the connection in case of a big issue.
- An exponential time interval before each retry, including some randomness to avoid all WebSocket clients to reconnect at the same time (and avoid a flooding of requests at server side).

You can find the complete implementation I did here : https://github.com/icure-io/icure-medical-device-js-sdk/blob/master/src/utils/rsocket.ts